# I can't install ocaml plugin in my eclipse

Tags: installation, 12.04, programming, eclipse

I installed eclipse with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu` but when i try to install OCAIDE with Help->Install New Software. Appears this error :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: org.eclipse.update.feature,OcaIDEFeature,1.2.15.201204281554.
http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/features/OcaIDEFeature_1.2.15.201204281554.jar
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,Ocaml,1.2.14.201204281554.
http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/plugins/Ocaml_1.2.14.201204281554.jar
```

Can you help me? Im desperate because i need this for a college work.

Comment: You should try using the eclipse version from their web page, because eclipse can be sensitive about it's components when it comes to installing new plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it worked for me

Install both eclipse and eclipse-pde.  These are the packages I have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp
```

Add the site: `http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/ocaml/site.xml` as a software source

Help->Install New Software
Select OCaml

You get this:
[image]

I suspect you're missing something that's in these:
`eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp`